# Difference between render and model in Grails

Tags: grails

What is the difference between render and model in Grails?

**Example**
render(text : map.toJson(list),contentType:"text/json")
[text : map.toJson(list)]

Comment: Check [this][1] link.may be it helps

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601188/grails-controller-rendering-method-render-vs-respond

Comment: in what context?  please provide at least a code snipped or doc reference of what you are thinking here.  we can not read minds, yaknow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must go through the Grails Documentation first for a more detailed understanding. However, in any RAD (Rapid Application Development) Framework, these concepts are identical.

***render*** in any sense is used to render something as a response. This is decided by the key words you use. For example in your question, you have asked the action in your controller to send a response to a request as a JSON string.In your question, the map is the model.

***Model*** on the other hand is what you are **trying to render**. To put in simply, model is an object. This object could contain a single object like a Domain entity or it could contain a lot more. In grails, you would generally use ***model*** as a **keyword** when your trying to render a view or a template. The model is passed on to the template and you can have access to the objects in the model directly.