# Render complex object in JSON in grails

Tags: json, grails

I have complex object and I want to render it, but I have several problems in view.

First of all, I have UUID field in my class but in View I get not the String but mostSigBits and leastSigBits.
The second one, I have my enums fields like two fields with enum and value

For example,

```
public class ExampleObject   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private UUID id;

  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty("address")
  private String address;

  @JsonProperty("port")
  private String port;

  @JsonProperty("users")
  @Valid
  private List<UserRef> users = null;

  @JsonProperty("indexingParameters")
  private IndexingParameters indexingParameters;

  @JsonProperty("otherParameters")
  private OtherParameters otherParameters;

  @JsonProperty("status")
  private Status status;
}
```

When I get response from controller I get answer with this one

```
{
   "id": {
        "leastSignificantBits": -5406850341911646206,
        "mostSignificantBits": 8884977146336383467
    },
   "status": {
        "enumType": "api.model.Status",
        "name": "GENERAL"
    }
....
}
```

The problem is I have a lot of different but with the same problem objects in my code. If there is only 1 object, I`d easy prepare some _exampleObject.gson template and render every answer from controller to it, but I have many objects.

I think there are some variants to render correct my JSON, isn`t there?

---

Another rendering variants where `data` is ExampleObject.class or something like that

1)code:

```
  Map map = [content: data.content, sorting: data.sorting, paging: data.paging] as Map
    render AppResponse.success([success: true, data: map]).asJSON()
  
render data as JSON
```

on front:

```
Incorrect UUID and DateTime convert each field in Object, But I need Timeshtamp

   "id": {"leastSignificantBits": -5005002633583312101,
          "mostSignificantBits": 4056748206401340307},
   "key": "b48d35dd-0551-4265-a1b1-65105e713811",
```

2)code:

```
Map map =  [data: new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(data)] as Map
render map
```

on front:

```
Here we can see square brackets at the start  which is wrong for JSON

['data':'{"content":[{"id":"384c7700-09c1-4393-ba8a-a89f555f431b","name":"somename"...
```

3)code:

```
Object result = new HashMap<String, Object>()

result.success = true
result["data1"] = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(data)

render result as JSON
```

on front:

```
Here we can see quotes escaping

"data": "{\"content\":[{\"id\":\"384c7700-09c1-4393-ba8a-a89f555f431b\",\"name\":\"somename\",\"key\":\"b48d35dd-0551-4265-a1b1-65105e713811\",\"status\":\"COMPLETED\.......
```

Comment: Have you tried mapping the response without gson? You can fill a Map to store the data as a JSON and return it.

Comment: I did, but i got not correct JSON. If i send to fron only Map like `[name: myname, id: myId] as Map`, so it will be correct, but if I try `render [result: myObject] as Map` where "myObject" is example of MyObject.class i get wrong rendering

Comment: Try to save the data into variable before send the respond and parse it with JSON object, somthing like that `def test = [test: object.test] as JSON; respond test`. Check if the respond runs. Check this question about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601188/grails-controller-rendering-method-render-vs-respond]

Comment: I added 3 examples of my tries. Problem is in that, I got that object from rest request from another endpoin, convert LazyMap to my ExampleObject  do some logic and have to send my object to front. ExampleObject   is not domain object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this

```
@CompileStatic
class MyProxyController {


@Autowired
Myservice service

static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
          .registerModule(new JodaModule())
          .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
          .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false)
          .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)


def getExampleObject {
  ExampleObject exampleObject = service.getExampleObject()

  render([contentType: "application/json"], objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new CustomObject(data, true)))

}

  @CompileStatic
  class CustomObject {
    Boolean success
    Object data

    CustomObject(Object data, Boolean success) {
      this.data = data
      this.success = success
    }
  }

}
```

And get json as I wanted like

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "content": [
            { ....
```